# Compiling native client's hello_world.c

Tags: c, google-nativeclient

In the pepper_21 examples folder is a hello_world.c file I'm trying to compile. Here's the command I'm using:

```
$NACL_SDK_ROOT/toolchain/linux_x86_newlib/bin/x86_64-nacl-gcc hello_world.c -o a.nexe -lppapi
```

And here's the error:

```
hello_world.c: In function ‘Instance_DidCreate’:
hello_world.c:86: error: ‘TCNAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

I adapted the command from [this page](https://developers.google.com/native-client/devguide/devcycle/building). How can it successfully be compiled?

Comment: The least you can do is post relevant code. No one here works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see by inspecting the Makefile that TCNAME is defined on the command line.

```
x86_64-nacl-gcc hello_world.c -o a.nexe -lppapi -DTCNAME=newlib
```

OR

```
x86_64-nacl-gcc hello_world.c -o a.nexe -lppapi -DTCNAME=glibc
```

Depending on which version of the toolchain you are using.